# SQLite Query Not Running in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I created a database using DB Browser for SQLite. Now I am trying to run queries to retrieve data from the database, and I have run into an issue. When I run the query in DB Browser, the query runs smoothly. When I attempt to run the same query in Java, I get an error message. I triple-checked the query string. I looked to make sure I was not using `SQLite` keywords incorrectly. Why am I getting an error when I run this query Java?

```
SELECT
    subject.id, main.name, main.link, subject.name, main_subject.weight
FROM 
    main_subject
LEFT JOIN 
    main ON main_subject.mainId = main.id
LEFT JOIN 
    subject ON main_subject.subjectId = subject.id
```

**The query running correctly in DB Browser.**
[image]

**MCVE:**

**Main**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try (DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler()) {
            List<BySubjectItemTwo> bySubjectItemTwos = databaseHandler.getBySubjectItems();
            bySubjectItemTwos.forEach(System.out::println);
            //databaseHandler.getByTitleItems().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class DatabaseHandler implements AutoCloseable
{

    String dbString = "jdbc:sqlite:qDatabase.sqlite3";
    private Connection conn;

    public DatabaseHandler()
    {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbString);
            System.out.println("Connected to qDatabase!");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        conn.close();
    }

    public List<BySubjectItemTwo> getBySubjectItems()
    {
        List<BySubjectItemTwo> returnList = new ArrayList();

        String sqlString = "SELECT subject.id, main.name, main.link, subject.name, main_subject.weight FROM main_subject LEFT JOIN main ON main_subject.mainId = main.id LEFT JOIN subject ON main_subject.subjectId = subject.id";
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("subject.id") + " - " + rs.getString("main.name") + " - " + rs.getString("main.link") + " - " + rs.getString("subject.name") + " - " + rs.getInt("main_subject.weight"));
                //returnList.add(new BySubjectItemTwo(rs.getInt("subject.id"), rs.getString("main.name"), rs.getString("main.link"), rs.getString("subject.name"), rs.getInt("main_subject.weight")));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return returnList;
    }  
}
```

**BySubjectItemTwo**

```
/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class BySubjectItemTwo
{

    private int subjectId;
    private String mainName;
    private String mainLink;
    private String subjectName;
    private int mainSubjectWeight;

    public BySubjectItemTwo(int subjectId, String mainName, String mainLink, String subjectName, int mainSubjectWeight)
    {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
        this.mainName = mainName;
        this.mainLink = mainLink;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.mainSubjectWeight = mainSubjectWeight;
    }

    public int getSubjectWeight()
    {
        return mainSubjectWeight;
    }

    public void setSubjectWeight(int mainSubjectWeight)
    {
        this.mainSubjectWeight = mainSubjectWeight;
    }

    public int getSubjectId()
    {
        return subjectId;
    }

    public void setSubjectId(int subjectId)
    {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }

    public String getMainName()
    {
        return mainName;
    }

    public void setMainName(String mainName)
    {
        this.mainName = mainName;
    }

    public String getMainLink()
    {
        return mainLink;
    }

    public void setMainLink(String mainLink)
    {
        this.mainLink = mainLink;
    }

    public String getSubjectName()
    {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName)
    {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("BySubjectItemTwo{subjectId=").append(subjectId);
        sb.append(", mainName=").append(mainName);
        sb.append(", mainLink=").append(mainLink);
        sb.append(", subjectName=").append(subjectName);
        sb.append(", subjectWeight=").append(mainSubjectWeight);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
----------< sed.work:CreateDatabaseByTitleAndSubjectDatabase >----------
Building CreateDatabaseByTitleAndSubjectDatabase 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ CreateDatabaseByTitleAndSubjectDatabase ---
Connected to qDatabase!
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous column name: subject.id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.484 s
Finished at: 2020-10-16T12:42:35-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Netbean's Info**

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.1
Java: 15; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15+36-1562
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 15+36-1562
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
Maven Project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
FROM main_subject, main, subject
```

is the problem with your query.

Remove `, main, subject` from your statement.
The tables `main` and `subject` are correctly joined after the `LEFT` joins.
When you use them also in the `FROM` clause this creates additional references and `CROSS` joins to the same tables.

Also, although SQLite allows a query to return more than 1 columns with the same name, it is a good practice to alias columns so that in the resultset all column names are different.
So give aliases to `main.name` and `subject.name`, something like this:

```
SELECT subject.id, main.name AS main_name, ..., subject.name AS subject_name, ...
```

and when you retrieve the column values don't use the table prefixes:

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") + " - " + rs.getString("main_name") + " - " + rs.getString("link") + " - " + rs.getString("subject_name") + " - " + rs.getInt("weight"));
```

Comment: Hello @forpas. Sorry, I updated the String. I was trying different stuff out and came up with that incorrect String.

Comment: @Sedrick if you run the query as it was before you edited with: `FROM main_subject, main, subject` in DB Browser for SQLite you will get the error: `ambiguous column name: subject.id` just like the error message you get. So the actual code that produces this error is not the code that you have currently in your question.

Comment: Hello forpas, I copied and pasted directly from DB Browser. I also typed the String directly. I also cleaned and build my project.

Comment: @Sedrick As I said this query does not throw this error but the previous does.

Comment: Hello forpas, `String sqlString = "SELECT subject.id, main.name, main.link, subject.name, main_subject.weight FROM main_subject LEFT JOIN main ON main_subject.mainId = main.id LEFT JOIN subject ON main_subject.subjectId = subject.id";`
 is the String I am currently using. It's giving me the error.

Comment: Thanks, forpas. The second part of your answer did the trick. I think there was a conflict with how I named things.